# Is it advised to create multiple LUIS models using dispatch?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker, formflow

Requirement: I need to enable bot to handle QnAs, talk to SharePoint list for dynamic form flows and return custom designed cards/actions, preconfigured troubleshooting services with common questions and integration of Service Now etc.

Question: Since the bot is doing more than one, should I consider designing individual LUIS models and use dispatcher service? or could I build it using multiple intends with single LUIS model?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what dispatcher is designed for.

Comment: Thank you. If that's the case then what's the use of multiple intends? I could manage the same thing using multiple intends as well. Could you help me in clarifying it?